# How to query string pattern stored inside array in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of salons, now there's an array of keywords inside a salon. for example

```
SalonModel {
String salonName;
String salonAddress;
List<String> keywords; (eg: ["hairdresser","covid-19","free coffee"])
}
```

Now if i type hair inside search field i want to somehow query in firebase to match all the tags with hair in it ( for eg "hairdresser" matches with "hair" ) and return those salons doc which have hair keyword in it. Is there any approach to do that or any alternative way ?

Comment: I think this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444), might help. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks that helps, Only the last thing i want to ask that : can we do a "startsWith"  query in a list of strings/keywords stored inside a doc ?

Comment: No, you cannot do that with an array.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that you've got a well-designed and working search bar in your Flutter front end application, you can:

1. Query Firebase with simple queries, [such as these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any);
2. Implement a Backend middleware that handles a simple search engine, but that's another toppic.

The point here is that, to my knowledge, Firestore is meant to be a Database, whereas a Search Engine is just another story.